# Does update query overwrite records with same values in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Does an `Update` query `updates/overwrites`(or ??) existing values if the existing values are same as the one your updating with?

This question is in reference to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: It updates whatever fits your WHERE clause or every record if you don't include one

Comment: @SurajSingh - `sql` is structured query language. It definitely does not imply a specific DBMS.

Comment: @SurajSingh: I saw the tag SQL and that is ***NOT*** a tag for a DBMS. That is a general tag for ANSI SQL questions.

Comment: If you tell SQL Server to `UPDATE` some rows - it will update those rows. SQL Server doesn't do any "matching" of its own. That's up to you - you control the `WHERE` clause for the `UPDATE`. If you want to avoid updating some rows - make sure the `WHERE` clause excludes them.

Comment: This is looked at in [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith So you can give a generalized answer , so that i can gain my question was about updating but if you tell me it's different for different RDBMS systems then it's a add-on for me , So you can give me a general idea.

Comment: @SurajSingh - For SQL Server see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then sorry i wasn't aware of it .

Comment: @Suraj That is basic question.Not any reasearch done.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar Well it was not a well formed question, Actually i wanted to know behavior of transaction logs when this(described in question) happens.

Comment: @Suraj Please read first then send any comments about my answer please read what Nisar has said "this lines helped me. thanks vaibhav parmar"

Comment: @Suraj Thats important that only one google search answer the qestion thats stupid that no one google and post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't write the query not to, yes. So consider the following query:

```
UPDATE a SET fa = 'hello'
```

that's going to update the field `fa` and set it to `hello` regardless. However, if you wrote something like:

```
UPDATE a SET fa = 'hello' WHERE fa <> 'hello'
```

then it would only update *if* the value were not `hello`. Now, on a grander scale this is often called **optimistic concurrency.** I only want to update the row **if** the row is what it was when I first retrieved it.

However, the question overall is a little weird. Of course it will overwrite the field, but it doesn't really matter, it's the same value.

Comment: And what's the delete vote for? Oh, and the down vote? I mean if you disagree, let me know why.